# An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing 'src/theme.js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, storybook

So this error has been a bit of a mystery to me and I'm having trouble figuring out how to resolve it.

I have a `theme.ts` file that more or less looks like this below:

```
import { AgnosticStyles, ThemeParameters } from 'styled-components';
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const agnosticStyles: AgnosticStyles = {
  font: {
    weight: {
      light: '300',
      normal: '400',
      bold: '600',
    },
  },
};
...
// more themes

const defaultTheme = {
  lightTheme,
  darkTheme,
};

export default defaultTheme;
```

in my `Button.stories.txs` file, when I try to import it *the same way I import everything else*... I get the following error in storybook:

[image]

Okay, so I gues I need to then write `theme.ts`, however that does two things. One, it creates the error shown below and two, it breaks the intellisense that comes with VsCode TS.

[image]

---

How can I fix my `Button.stories.tsx` file so the import path error with go away and I can just import as `src/theme`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include your `*.tsx` files in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ....
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Hello, current `tsconfig` looks like this: `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "next-env.d.ts", "next.config.js"]`

Comment: @kevin have you closed/reopened vsCode? sometimes it won't pick up the new options until you do...

Comment: good suggestion, fully closed out of VScode and restarted the program. Unfortunately, the error still persists.

Comment: if I leave the import in my `Button.stories.tsx` file like this: `import defaultTheme from 'src/theme';` I can still build / run my dev environment successfully, however my storybook environment fails (first screenshot above) ... don't know if that narrows it down at all.

Comment: @kevin misread at first - just remove the `.ts`. Change to `import defaultTheme from './src/theme';`

Comment: No worries! I think I actually just solved it and I'm kinda stumped why this came up at all. So, I hand-wrote the import path and it resolved it to `import defaultTheme from '../../theme';` .. and now it works. What's really confusing me is why `src/theme.ts` was able to somehow find my (correct) styles despite the fact that that is not the right path to the `theme` file ... it needs to be `../../theme`

Comment: to extend on that, `src/theme.ts` magically found my styles, yet `src/theme` said to make it a "js" file or whatever (in vscode) instead of just saying it cannot resolve the path (like it does in storybook) ... how weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have received this problem when create types from swagger. So my new file from it is located in external folder and isn't visiable for other files, but my internal modules are visiable.
I solved it like this:

tsconfig.json - > "baseUrl": "./", -> reload project

I think this issue is related to scopes of visibility

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lcQS.png)